# Blocking shouldOverrideUrlLoading in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to develop a custom webview app where in only google safe browsing sites will be opened in webview.
For that I need to send url requested in webview to google first, wait for google safe browsing api response and if safe then load the url in webview.

For that I am intercepting url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading, and sending an http request from there. But since shouldOverrideUrlLoading is called on UI thread, I get networkonmainthread exception. I can send request in async task but it wont stop webview from loading the url.

Is there any way by which I can block shouldOverrideUrlLoading without getting ANR or networkonmainthread  exception?

Comment: Have a boolean storing if `next Address can be overriden?`. In your shouldOverrideUrl, check whether it's true or false. If true, then just `return true;`, otherwise, display an `please wait` overlay, launch your request and `return false`. When receiving response from your httpRequest, either update the boolean and force page reloading (by calling the URL again) or pormpt the user that he can't access this URL. (And don't forget to dismiss the overlay)

Comment: Facing the same situation at the moment, did you ever get a solution for this @simplyamey ?